# python sqlite not returning None even though it is None?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

This is an assignment I have to do for an online course. We are learning about data modeling and relational  databases. For this assignment, We have to take input data from an iTunes xml playlist file and put them into a database. Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb14.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER,
    genre_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT ,
    genre_id INTEGER

);
''')


fname =('C:/Users/Jeremiah/Desktop/Python/code3/tracks/Library.xml')
#if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    #print(name, artist, album, count, rating, length,genre)


    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''',(genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    if (cur.fetchone()) is None or (cur.fetchone() is 'None'):
        print('Here')
    else:
        print(cur.fetchone())
    genre_id = None

    #print (name)
    #print(artist)
    #print(genre_id)

    if genre_id is not None:

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (genre_id)
        VALUES (?)''',(genre_id, ))

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
            (title, album_id, len, rating, count)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
            ( name, album_id, length, rating, count ) )
        genre_id = None
        conn.commit()
        continue


    else:

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Genre (genre_id)
            VALUES (?)''',(genre, ))

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
            (title, album_id, len, rating, count)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
            ( name, album_id, length, rating, count ) )
        #genre_id = None
    conn.commit()
print('done')
```

I need to put the `genre_id` into the track table. But when I run the code including `genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]`, I get the error: `NoneType is not subscriptable`. So, I tried printing out `cur.fetchone()` to see which values returned `None`. I used    `is not None`    to try to find the values of `cur.fetchone()` that return `None`, but when I print out every value of `cur.fetchone()`, it still prints out `None` sometimes.

How can I weed out the cases where `cur.fetchone()` is `None` ?

I've been stuck for days.

Thank you in advance for the help!!!

Edit:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb14.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER,
    genre_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT ,
    genre_id INTEGER

);
''')


fname =('C:/Users/Jeremiah/Desktop/Python/code3/tracks/Library.xml')
#if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    #print(name, artist, album, count, rating, length,genre)
    #cur.execute('SELECT id from ')

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''',(genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    print (name)
    print(artist)
    print(genre_id)

    if genre_id is not None:

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (genre_id)
        VALUES (?)''',(genre_id, ))

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
            (title, album_id, len, rating, count)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
            ( name, album_id, length, rating, count ) )
        genre_id = None
        conn.commit()
        continue


    else:

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Genre (genre_id)
            VALUES (?)''',(genre, ))

        cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
            (title, album_id, len, rating, count)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
            ( name, album_id, length, rating, count ) )
        #genre_id = None
    conn.commit()
print('done')
```

[Command: python -u C:\Users\Jeremiah\Desktop\Python\code3\tracks\tracks.py]
Dict count: 404
Another One Bites The Dust
Queen
1
Asche Zu Asche
Rammstein
3
Beauty School Dropout
Various
5
Black Dog
Led Zeppelin
1
Bring The Boys Back Home
Pink Floyd
1
Circles
Bryan Lee
11
Comfortably Numb
Pink Floyd
1
Crazy Little Thing Called Love
Queen
1
Electric Funeral
Black Sabbath
17
Fat Bottomed Girls
Queen
1
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)
AC/DC
1
Four Sticks
Led Zeppelin
1
Furious Angels
Rob Dougan
5
Gelle
Bryan Lee
27
Going To California
Led Zeppelin
1
Grease
Various
5
Hand of Doom
Black Sabbath
17
Hells Bells
AC/DC
1
Hey You
Pink Floyd
1
I Worry
Bryan Lee
27
Iron Man
Black Sabbath
17
Is There Anybody Out There?
Pink Floyd
1
It was a Very Good Year
Frank Sinatra
45
Its Your Move
Bryan Lee
27
Jack the Stripper/Fairies Wear Boots
Black Sabbath
17
Killer Queen
Queen
1
Laichzeit
Rammstein
3
Let me Down Easy
Bryan Lee
27
Misty Mountain Hop
Led Zeppelin
1
No Low Down
Bryan Lee
27
Now You Are Gone
America
45
Outside The Wall
Pink Floyd
1
Paranoid
Black Sabbath
17
Planet Caravan
Black Sabbath
17
Pretty Jeanie
Bryan Lee
27
Rammstein
Rammstein
3
Rat Salad
Black Sabbath
17
Rock & Roll
Led Zeppelin
1
Rode Across the Desert
America
45
Sandy
Various
5
Shake Your Foundations
AC/DC
1
Sister Golden Hair
America
45
Somebody To Love
Queen
1
Stairway To Heaven
Led Zeppelin
1
Strangers in the Night
Frank Sinatra
45
Summer Nights
Various
5
Summer Wind
Frank Sinatra
45
Thats Life
Frank Sinatra
45
The Battle Of Evermore
Led Zeppelin
1
The Blues "Is"
Bryan Lee
27
There it Is
Bryan Lee
27
Think
Bryan Lee
27
This Town
Frank Sinatra
45
Tin Man
America
45
Track 01
Billy Price
27
Track 02
Billy Price
27
Track 03
Billy Price
27
Messin with the Kid
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Track 04
Billy Price
27
Stormy Monday
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Track 05
Billy Price
27
Waiting on Ice
Bryan Lee
27
War Pigs/Luke's Wall
Black Sabbath
17
We Are The Champions
Queen
1
We Will Rock You
Queen
1
When Somebody Loves You
Frank Sinatra
45
When The Levee Breaks
Led Zeppelin
1
You are the One that I Want
Various
5
You Done Me Wrong
Bryan Lee
27
You Shook Me All Night Long
AC/DC
1
You're My Best Friend
Queen
1
Zion
Fluke
5
Who Made Who
AC/DC
1
D.T.
AC/DC
1
Sink the Pink
AC/DC
1
Ride On
AC/DC
1
Chase the Ace
AC/DC
1
Wollt Ihr Das Bett In Flammen Sehen
Rammstein
3
Der Meister
Rammstein
3
Weisses Fleisch
Rammstein
3
Seemann
Rammstein
3
Du Riechst So Gut
Rammstein
3
Das Alte Leid
Rammstein
3
Heirate Mich
Rammstein
3
Herzeleid
Rammstein
3
Baba O'Riley
The Who
1
Bargain
The Who
1
Love Ain't for Keeping
The Who
1
My Wife
The Who
1
The Song Is Over
The Who
1
Getting In Tune
The Who
1
Going Mobile
The Who
1
Behind Blue Eyes
The Who
1
Won't Get Fooled Again
The Who
1
Folsom Prison Blues
Johnny Cash
189
I Walk The Line
Johnny Cash
189
Get Rhythm
Johnny Cash
189
Big River
Johnny Cash
189
Guess Things Happen That Way
Johnny Cash
189
Ring Of Fire
Johnny Cash
189
Jackson
Johnny Cash
189
A Boy Named Sue (live)
Johnny Cash
189
You Raise Me Up
Selah
205
Hold On, I'm Coming
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Got my Mojo Working
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Sweet Home Chicago
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Heavy Love
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Cold Cold Feeling
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Lonely Avenue
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Good Morning Little Schoolgirl
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Dust My Broom
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Gimme' Some Lovin
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Everybody Needs Somebody to Love
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Black Magic Woman
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Steppin' Rooster
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Our Love is Drifting
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Doin' 100
The Canettes Blues Band
27
Mother Joy
Matt Ender
235
Soldier's Lament
Steve McDonald
235
Dulaman
Altan
235
The Arrow
Chris Spheeris
235
Spanish Eyes
La Esperanza
235
Banana Bay
Luis Villegas
235
Aguas De Marco
Rosa Passos
235
Tamborea
Energipsy
235
Gone
Hollie Smith
235
The Immigrant
Joanie Madden
235
Pahrump-Big Water
Cusco
235
Seeker's Quest
Cheryl Gunn
235
Floating To Forever
Dean Everson
235
Open Road
Jeff Bailey
261
Ruby
Kaiser Chiefs
263
The Angry Mob
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Heat Dies Down
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Highroyds
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Love's Not A Competition (But I'm Winning)
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Thank You Very Much
Kaiser Chiefs
263
I Can Do It Without You
Kaiser Chiefs
263
My Kind Of Guy
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Everything Is Average Nowadays
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Learnt My Lesson Well
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Try Your Best
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Retirement
Kaiser Chiefs
263
The Angry Mob [Live From Berlin]
Kaiser Chiefs
263
I Like To Fight
Kaiser Chiefs
263
From The Neck Down
Kaiser Chiefs
263
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeremiah\Desktop\Python\code3\tracks\tracks.py", line 89, in 
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[Finished in 1.415s]

Comment: Can you update with the full stack trace including the line number?

Comment: I updated it Erik. Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the formatting for the last block or remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I understand that `cur.fetchone()` returns `None`
You are getting an error because you are running: `None[0]`.

When you `cur.fetchone()` it will actually output one item from the cursor and also delete it, the item will popped, and in your case it will be lost!
So instead of running `cur.fetchone()` several times you should save it in a variable like:

```
res = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that!  I tried putting in the code      genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]    followed by  print(genre_id).   It would print out a few values, then I get the error:  genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]. Nonetype object is not subscriptable.

Comment: @J.slack you're welcome, approve answer so it can close your question.

Comment: How do I approve? I'm new to SO